# new python user..printing txt file with .read, not working

Tags: python, printing

I'm reading How to Learn Python the Hard Way by Zed Shaw and I can't get this part right. I'm trying to rewrite the contents of a txt file and then print it, my last line wont work(nothing shows up after I print "I'm going to write these to the file."), it seems like it works until I add the .read command...

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN"

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print open(filename).read()
```

Comment: *"my last line wont work"* -- what does it mean? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that nothing comes up on powershell after the print line "I'm going to write these to the file."

Comment: it is ok. Don't put it in the comment, [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `target.close()` or `target.flush()` so that the newly written content would be available for `.read()`.

Comment: @newpythonuser1102 If that worked, than it would be good idea to accept the anwser.

Answer (score 1):

from reviewing the website that you got this code from you didnt properly complete typing in the last 2 lines that zed shaw had typed from http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html:

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()